# Запись в таблицу с произвольным именем NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

В `Mapping.hbm.xml` описано вот это:

```
<class name="ClassFOO, ExeName" table="Table1">
  <!-- -->
</class>
```

Но дело в том, что имя таблицы приходит из вне, а значит нужно менять это самое Table1 на лету, как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение найдено:

```
_nhConfiguration = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
_nhConfiguration.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

foreach (NHibernate.Mapping.PersistentClass tt in  _nhConfiguration.ClassMappings)
{
    if (tt.ClassName.IndexOf("Класс для которого меняем таблицу") == 0 && TableName != null)
        tt.Table.Name = TableName;
}
_sessionFactory = _nhConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Суть в том, что перед созданием `ISessionFactory` редактируем конфиг, а именно меняем имя таблицы на нужное, а потом создаем фэктори.